# Grammar for json schema

Tags: json, validation, schema, grammar

I would like to write a validator for json files that conforms to the json schema paradigm. I've been looking for a grammar that describes json schema without any luck. Do you know if there is any formal description of the json schema specifications that I can use to write a parser?

Thank you.

f.

Comment: Check out [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/). It is an open source project; the code is available on github. JSON grammar is also described at http://www.json.org/.

Comment: Chris, I'm looking for a grammar that describes the json schema. I already know how to parse a json file to check if its syntax conforms to the json grammar

Comment: Why do you need grammar? Isn't this enough? http://json-schema.org/

Comment: with a grammar writing the validation class would be much easier than trying to follow the json schema syntax from the documentation (which is what I am currently doing...)

Answer (score 1):

The meta-schema is at http://json-schema.org/schema

The semantics are defined in http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html